# Почему первый код быстрее второго?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Просьба, если несложно, немного "разжевать" процесс. Например, когда я после `FROM` объявляю таблицу, параметров которой нет в `SELECT`, насколько это затратно. Почему так не делают?

```
SELECT a.model, price
FROM (
  SELECT model, price FROM PC
  UNION
  SELECT model, price FROM Laptop
  UNION
  SELECT model, price FROM Printer
) AS a
JOIN Product p ON a.model = p.model
WHERE p.maker = 'B';
```

```
SELECT p.model,p.price
FROM printer p, product prod
WHERE maker='B' AND p.model=prod.model
UNION
SELECT l.model,l.price
FROM laptop l, product prod
WHERE maker='B' AND l.model=prod.model
UNION
SELECT pc.model,pc.price FROM pc, product prod
WHERE maker='B' AND pc.model=prod.model
```

Comment: *Почему первый код быстрее второго?* Это частный случай. В зависимости от структуры и данных может быть и быстрее, и медленнее, и неразличимо.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте посмотрим что и как прочитайте что вы написали.

Разберем сначала [Union](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/queries-union)

> UNION по сути добавляет результаты второго запроса к результатам
> первого (хотя никакой порядок возвращаемых строк при этом не
> гарантируется). Более того, эта операция убирает дублирующиеся строки
> из результата так же, как это делает DISTINCT, если только не указано
> UNION ALL.

1. Объединить отфильтровать

   - 3 таблицы объединяем 1 раз фильтруем.

   ```
   SELECT a.model, price 
   FROM (
       SELECT model, price FROM PC 
       UNION
       SELECT model, price FROM Laptop
       UNION
       SELECT model, price FROM Printer
    ) AS a 
   JOIN Product p ON a.model = p.model
   WHERE p.maker = 'B';
   ```
2. Отфильтровать объединить

   - 3 таблицы фильтруем и обединяем 3 таблицы

   ```
   SELECT p.model,p.price 
   FROM printer p, product prod
   WHERE maker='B' AND p.model=prod.model
   UNION
   SELECT l.model,l.price 
   FROM laptop l, product prod
   WHERE maker='B' AND l.model=prod.model
   UNION
   SELECT pc.model,pc.price FROM pc, product prod
   WHERE maker='B' AND pc.model=prod.model
   ```

А вообще рекомендую сделать так

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.model, price 
FROM (
    SELECT model, price FROM PC 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT model, price FROM Laptop
    UNION ALL
    SELECT model, price FROM Printer
 ) AS a 
JOIN Product p ON a.model = p.model
 AND p.maker = 'B';
```

**PS.** Возращаясь к основному вопросу. ***Почему первый код быстрее второго?*** - На самом деле всё зависит от задач и количества данных. Собрать данные в одну таблицу потом фильтровать не всегда быстрее чем подготовить и объединить. [пример](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136653/filtering-union-all-result-is-much-slower-than-filtering-each-subquery)

К вопросу плохой практики. Это часть синтаксиса. Хорош или плох вот так вот я бы не судил. Я очень редко объединяю таблицы. Поскольку вижу смысл разделения только в ускорении и уменьшении данных. Все данные которые должны объединяться могут спокойно подождать и не расходовать слишком много ресурсов.

Comment: Может поясните почему  -. Я подправлю ответ если кого-то он не устраивает